# Asymptotic Notation more specifically, Big-O notation

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

How the functions in the class $O(d)^d$ and $\epsilon^{1/O(d.4^d)}$ looks like..?
where $\epsilon$<1. 
I am really confused with this complicated Big-O notations 
Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Big-$O$ is, as $x \rightarrow \infty$:

$$f(x) = O[g(x)] \implies \exists (M,N) : |f(x)| \le M|g(x)| \; \forall \, x > N $$

In the first example you provided, I would say, rather that you have some function

$$h(d) = O(d^d) $$

which means that $h(d)$ must satisfy

$$|h(d)| \le M d^d$$

as $d \rightarrow \infty$.  Examples of such functions would be $h(d) = d^{d-1}$, $h(d) = (d-1)^d$, $h(d) = 2^d$, etc.

In your second example, note that in estimating that quantity, you could replace $O(d \, 4^d)$ with something smaller, say $4^d$, which implies a larger power of $\epsilon$, which means a smaller number.  Thus, $\epsilon^{1/(d 4^d)}$ is an upper bound on the value of that term.